# В чем преимущества однокорневой иерархии классов?

Tags: ооп, классы

В чем заключаются основные преимущества однокорневой иерархии классов, когда все классы наследуются от одного класса, например `Object`? Что побудило разработчиков языков с однокорневой иерархией классов пойти именно по этому пути?

Comment: А вы можете уточнить преимущества по сравнению с чем? К примеру, знаю, что в Java и C# всё наследуется от `Object`. А с чем сравнить эти преимущества?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov преимущества которые побудили разработчиков языков с одним корнем пойти по именно такому пути

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Главным образом для того, чтобы у всех объектов и классов было общее поведение, а также поведение по умолчанию, которое содержится в виртуальных методах, которые можно переопределить. Для этого лучше всего походит единый корневой объект. Это гарантирует, что у всех типов будут определённые методы.
2. Для того, чтобы можно было писать члены (методы, свойства, индексаторы, события и т.д.), которые могут по-разному работать с абсолютно непохожими типами. Однако эта возможность сильно нивелировалась более удобными Generic и удалила необходимость проверки типов и приведений, ошибки в которых можно было увидеть во время исполнения. Однако по-прежнему существует API (в том числе и стандартное), которое было разработано до Generic, и в котором активно используется корневой тип.

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю на счет преимуществ, но, как мне кажется, вполне логично **иногда** (иногда потому, что не надо это везде впихивать к месту и не к месту) определить общую часть, которая может быть у классов-наследников. И получается иногда так, что при анализе и построении будущей структуры (иерархии) выходит, что все классы будут иметь какие-то общие поля, методы (Естественно процесс выстроения иерархии занимает не день и, порой, даже не месяц. Это надо помнить). Так в *C#* и *Java* есть метод `toString`, который возвращает строковое представление объекта, `Finalize` — в котором можно описать логику, когда объект уничтожается и другие поля/методы. Не было бы никакого смысла описывать эти методы постоянно в десятках других классах. Это, как минимум, избыточность.

Это как-то более естественно, в некоторой аналогии: есть кто считает, что люди произошли от Адама и Евы. А это своего рода та же иерархия и наследование от корня)) Такая иерархия более легка и для понимания: дерево, только растущее сверху вниз, имеющие общие корни, подпитка из одного источника, а не как насаждение кустарников, сорняков-вьюнков, за которыми не видно своего огорода и своих помидорок с огурчиками.

Answer (score 4):

Множественное наследование дает дополнительную гибкость и возможность повторного использования кода, но порождает ряд проблем, связанных с неоднозначностью, которая возникает, когда у двух или более предков нашего класса есть совпадающие по сигнатуре методы. Наиболее известная проблема - т. наз. "проблема ромба", когда мы наследуем одновременно от двух классов (назовем их, к примеру, A и B), являющихся потомками одного и того же общего для них предка, и каждый из наших двух предков по-своему переопределяет метод, определенный в общем предке, скажем `int common(int i)`. Когда код, использующий наш класс, вызовет его метод `common(33)`, какой из методов - A.common() или B.common() - должен выполняться?

Разные языки, в которых реализовано множественное наследование, по-разному решают возникающие проблемы, но в любом случае эти решения приводят к усложнению языка, порой к искусственным ограничениям и т. д.

В реальных проектах иерархии используемых классов обычно бывают довольно сложными и запутанными (достаточно посмотреть на стандартные библиотеки классов в любом нормальном языке), и проблемы множественного наследования в этих условиях могут превратиться в немалую головную боль, порождая уйму ошибок, которые бывает нелегко найти и исправить.

Кроме того, множественное наследование часто провоцирует программиста на использование запутанных и неоднозначных решений, способствующих появлению ошибок, в отличие от одиночного наследования, которое, как правило, обеспечивает большую логическую ясность и стройность решений, а значит, снижает вероятность ошибок.

Поэтому многие программисты (включая создателей Java) пришли к убеждению, что множественное наследование в чистом виде приносит больше геморроя и головной боли, чем гибкости, и отказались от него. А желаемая гибкость довольно успешно достигается другими средствами - интерфейсами, обобщенными классами и пр.

См. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ромбовидное_наследование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), ну и вообще поискать можно, где об этом пишут - напр. http://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0204/

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, автор не рассматривает целесообразность множественного наследования. Ему интересна целесообразность наследования (неявного в основном) от единого корневого типа. Даже несмотря на запрет множественного наследования, разработчики языков могли не создавать единый корневой тип, от которого будут наследоваться абсолютно все типы. Поэтому ваш ответ хорош, но абсолютно не подходит к данному вопросу.

Comment: Множественное наследование никак не связано с наличием/отсутствием класса `Object` (класс от которого всегда наследуются все остальные классы). Python3 - есть множественное наследование и общий `Object` класс; Java - нет множественного наследования, есть общий `Object`; C++ есть множественное наследование нет общего `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, в Java используется "простое" (не множественное) наследование, то без единого корня иерархии было бы сложно (не возможно) организовать контейнеры - list, map, etc.

Такая организация иерархии была в введена в Smalltalk  и многие языки взяли эту идею из него.

На мой взгляд подобная организация легче для понимания и уменьшает количество ошибок при разработке.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста мысль "то без единого корня иерархии было бы сложно (не возможно) организовать контейнеры - list, map, etc."

Comment: @VladimirGamalian возьмем List, у него есть метод add который добавляет новый элемент в список. У этого метода есть параметр. Параметр должен быть какого-то типа Если нет единого корня, то не возможно указать тип этого параметра, так что бы можно было поместить любой объект в этот список без дополнительных усилий.

Comment: А женерики это не про то разве?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а generics как раз и возможны из-за наличия единого корня. Почитайте про type erasure.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian и ещё про ко- и контрвариацию.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman type erasure - это особенность реализации генериков именно в Java. Тот же C#, откуда Java копировала реализацию, вполне обходится без Type erasure.

Comment: @PashaPash я упомяну type erasure только, что бы показать, что generic collection в java возможны лишь благодаря единому корню иерархии. Я не имел ввиду, что это единственный способ реализации коллекций.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman "возможны лишь благодаря" подразумевает что в java на момент внедрения генериков не было возможности реализовать их без type erasure и завязки на единый корень иерархии. Но ведь это явно не так - просто было принято решение удержать генерики в рамках compile-time фичи, и только поэтому генерики не решают проблему из вашего ответа. Т.е. вполне могли взять и сделать генерики с поддержкой примитивных типов - но не захотели.

Comment: @PashaPash в Java уже были коллекции на момент введения generics. Мой основной посыл - generics в Java используют "старую" реализацию коллекции основанную на едином корне. Я хотел показать, что "под капотом" там простые Object.

Answer (score 0):

Мое *imho* и не более того - что это в определенной степени замена обобщенного программирования. Например, лично мне еще до STL в C++ страшно хотелось написать класс-контейнер типа нынешнего вектора. Это было несложно сделать, для моих целей было сделано - но нужно было указать конкретный тип. В результате вариантов было два - либо для каждого типа заново переписывать код, либо порождать все классы, которые хотелось бы прятать в контейнер, от некоторого общего (при этом оказывались в пролёте фундаментальные типы). Шаблоны достаточно изящно решили эту проблему.

Насколько я знаю Java, там изначально пошли по другому пути, и дженерики - это уже возможность совершенно иного времени. Та же (поправьте, если ошибаюсь) даже фундаментальные типы в принципе являются классами. Этакое другое проектное решение, которое обеспечило замену обобщенного программирования в C++, и которое активно используется в самом языке - для того же преобразования, например, в строки.